# Weak Convergence under a Lipschitz Continuous Mapping

Tags: hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space. It is well-known that if $T:H\to H$ linear and continuous and $x_n\rightharpoonup x$, $(x_n)_n\subset H$, then $Tx_n\rightharpoonup Tx$. I am now wondering if this still holds true if we assume $T$ only to be Lipschitz continuous but not necessarily linear. A short argument or a counterexample is warmly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Say $H=\ell^2$, $x_n=e_n$. So $x_n\to0$ weakly.

Define $T:H\to H$ by $T(x)=||x||e_1.$ Then $T$ is Lipshitz, but $T(x_n)=e_1$, $T(0)=0$, so $T(x_n)$ does not tend weakly to $T(0)$.

Comment: do you know whether the assertion holds if we require $\|f(x_n)-x_n\|\to 0$ additionally?

Comment: the answer is positive.

Comment: @julian Really? Proof?

Comment: see answer below.

Answer (score 0):

If we add the assumption $\|f(x_n)-x_n\|\to 0$ we easily compute with the help of the Riesz representation theorem
$$
\lim_n\left(\|f(x)-x_n\|^2-\|x-x_n\|^2\right)=\|f(x)-x\|^2.
$$
Moreover, $\|f(x)-x_n\|\leq\|f(x)-f(x_n)\|+\|f(x_n)-x_n\|\leq L\|x-x_n\|+\|f(x_n)-x_n\|$ where $L$ is the Lipschitz constant of $f$. Eventually, we have
\begin{align}
\|f(x)-x\|^2&=\lim_n\left(\|f(x)-x_n\|^2-\|x-x_n\|^2\right)\\&\leq\lim_n\left(\|f(x_n)-x_n\|^2+2L\|f(x_n)-x_n\|\|x-x_n\|\right)\\&=0
\end{align}
since any weak convergent sequence is bounded.